# Who can help with this please?

Tags: interview-questions

[![enter image description her[image]

Im looking for answer for this please help me to find out,Thank you

Comment: With assignments like this, we must ask you to describe exactly what your current approach is, and how far you've gotten, **and to ask a question of your own**, such as "I was trying to answer this by doing abc, but abc requires knowledge of xyz, and xyz is not given; I tried calculating xyz from feh the following way {insert calculation}, but I'm stuck on how to derive x from fe. How can I do that? Is this the right approach?"

Comment: Please, show attempt to solve the problem, show your logic. Ask specific question about things you don't understand. Google some tutorials if you don't know where to start. "Hey can anyone solve my homework/interview problem" is not the way to go.

Comment: I don't know how OP can possibly show any working, because the task he was given is total garbage. I've written an answer, describing why. Maybe we should edit the question to reflect this rather than downvote it.

Comment: "Who can help with this please?" is not an explanatory question title. All questions on the site are looking for help. Can you improve it to explain the subject of the question?

Comment: @Transistor Fair enough, but I feel bad for OP. Rules are rules, though, and I get why SE insists on quality in the questions too.

Comment: -1 for poor question title, and not bothering to restate the problem in text.

Answer (score 5):

This "task" you have been given is awful. Here are my problems with it:

- It says the output of the IC is typically 5V. That statement is incongruous with that variable feedback network there. This circuit has an output anywhere between 5V and 10V, depending on the potentiometer position.
- An IC doesn't "have a resistance", and this particular 7805 output resistance is in the milliohms, not kilohms. The statement that it "has a resistance of 15kΩ" just doesn't make any sense.
- We are not told the potentiometer position, so we can't know what the output voltage is. We are forced to *assume* they mean the output is 5V.
- The output of the rectifier is 2A. If there's 2A coming out of the rectifier then all of it is also passing through the 7805, which must be completely broken, since it's internally current limited to 1.5A.
- The rectifier output is 35V. If that's true, what are the "9" and "0" markings on the transformer? I initially thought 9V, which if they are RMS voltages, would mean that the rectifier would have more like \$ 9V \times 1.4 - 2 \times 0.7V = 11V \$. Everything's ambiguous.
- They accept answers up to 3 decimal places, which is potentially 4 significant figures, but not a single value anywhere in this question or its diagram quotes more than two significant figures, and not a single resistor tolerance is known.
- They ask you to calculate the "power rating" of various things. That's not up to you, you can't calculate that. "Ratings" are things you find in datasheets, and are dependent upon heat sinking, ambient temperature. Maybe they mean "power dissipation", which would make more sense.
- When they ask for the power rating of the rectifier, it's not clear if they mean the maximum current/power it can handle itself (which comes from the datahseet, and depends on operating conditions), or maximum power it can deliver to its load.

I am absolutely horrified at the poor quality of this question, and can only assume that it was either

1. written by someone who hasn't a clue about these things, or
2. is designed to make you think all the things I've just said, and is expecting you to be critical of it in order to get any marks.

I doubt it's the latter, unfortunately, and I can't offer any calculations because absolutely nothing makes sense here.

Comment: It's possible (but unlikely) that previous pages/statements made this "task" more clear (based on the first step being numbered '3'). While it's good to try to salvage the question and help the OP, I still find that simply dumping a photo of homework on the site and expecting free help to be incredibly lazy and rude. My main objections (which have been discussed ad nauseam on meta) are: 1. this post is unlikely to be useful for future searches or visitors; 2. it reinforces that lazy questions can still get good answers, which IMO attracts more such behavior.